# send array from controller to javascript in view (laravel 5.4)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I want to send an array from my controller to a view and use it in a script tag in that view. In the script section, the array output is different from what I sent.

**My Controller :**

```
public function index()
{
    $arts = Art::all();
    $artistList = Artist::pluck('first_name','id');
    $artArr = $artistList->toArray();
    return view('admin.Art.index', compact(['arts','artistList','artArr']));
}
```

**My JavaScript in View:**

```
var artistList = {!! json_encode($artArr) !!};
    console.log(artistList);
```

**And output in console.log is:**

```
Object [ <1 empty slot>, "firstname edit", <3 empty slots>, "sahand", "karim", "amir ali", "amir", "ali" ]
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered html output?

Comment: Post the contents of `$artArr`. Try adding `dd($artArr);` in your controller and post the data.

Comment: i don't rendered anything yet, i just need some array list in my script like this: { 1:'name',2:'another name',3:'third' }

Comment: dd($artArr) output is: array:6 [▼
  1 => "firstname edit"
  5 => "sahand"
  6 => "karim"
  7 => "amir ali"
  8 => "amir"
  9 => "ali"
]

Comment: Untangled grammar to explain the question. Made differentiation clear between JavaScript and PHP.